# JFreeChart MultiPiePlot change title font colour

Tags: java, colors, jfreechart, title

JFreechart 1.0.14 dealing with MultiPiePlot.
Dataset is a `CategoryDataSet` with the category defining the Sub plot's title text.

I need to change the colour of the titles for each sub plot.

I am changing the background to black and need a contrasting title colour.
I've found how to change the colour of pretty much everything else.

In the below image the sub titles "`Response Pending`", "`Resplan Pending`" and "`Resolution Pending`" all need to be changed in colour.

[image: MultiPiePlot with sub titles]

I can't seem to access the Object to set the paint Colour anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
chart1.getTitle().setPaint(Color.RED);
```

Where char1 is the name of one of your charts?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to GrahamA for this. Thought I'd give some more detail for MultipPiePlot

For MultiPiePlot you can alter all titles with the following

```
// Get vars to control visual
p = (MultiplePiePlot) chart.getPlot();
JFreeChart subchart = p.getPieChart();
subchart.getTitle().setPaint(Color.red);
```

Getting the title of the main `chart.getTitle()` would alter the top title.